# Flutter Android TV App Rejected for D-Pad and Overscan

Tags: flutter, android-tv

I am, trying to get my Android app approved for Android TV but it is getting rejected with two issues:

- Missing DPad functionality
- Text cuts off edges of screen

[image: rejection notice]

I have tested the app on Android TV emulator and the app looks good and works with D-Pad.

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` I have these TV related entries:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

All my screens are wrapped with `SafeArea` widget which has additional minimum padding specified for TV. I was hoping this would fix the overscan problem but it hasn't:

```
SafeArea(
      minimum: isTv()
          ? const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 27.0, horizontal: 48.0)
          : EdgeInsets.zero,
```

All the controls that are not D-pad "aware" are wrapped with a `Focus` widget and I have implemented `onFocusChange` and `onKeyEvent` events to handle D-Pad, so all the controls are accessible though D-pad, there is a visual effect that indicates to users that the control is selected and users can use the controls using the D-Pad. I have tested this in the emulator and it works.

What else can I do to resolve these issues?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out it was my fault. I missed one screen. Kudos to Play Store testing!

Anyway, make sure that each screen is fully visible on TV, cannot use scrolling! And make sure each page can be navigated using D-Pad. All buttons/controls must be visible and accessible by D-Pad.

This includes dialogs and other screens that are not always visible.

Comment: I face similar issues, rejected twice for "Crashing after launch
Your app crashes after launch, which means we cannot review your app for Android TV inclusion. Please refer to our TV Activity documentation for details."

But app is working fine on the TV, I tested on a few decides.